# HTML to PDF converter using PHP

Tags: php, html, pdf, web, html-to-pdf

I work on one project, I used `html2pdf` by spipu but unfortunately I encountered problems at the end, such as problems with pictures and also rendering. My question is what would you recommend if I want to convert the automatically generated html into a php file to pdf on my own domain and site. My idea is something like this that my given html generated code, which already shows me a browser as it would convert to pdf (using html5 ...). Also, and this is probably the biggest problem I need to get rid of before and after element. I was looking at different kinds but some require api key and registering and then converting this html somewhere else, and I would like to avoid it.

Comment: `what would you recommend` is off topic for SO.

Answer (score 3):

I've used tcpdf in the past it works great and it's open source. 
Take a look at their [website](https://tcpdf.org/) they have plenty of examples that might get you going.
 Wanted to mention this answer as a comment since the question is vague but my SO reputation prevents me from that still..